# How setting 'nil' as a value of [String: String] dictionary is valid?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm curious why this snippet works correctly in Playground:

```
var dict = [String: String]()
dict["key"] = nil
let value = dict["key"]
```

we can see that I declared Dictionary with non optional values, after checking it in Playground it works similarly to dictionary declared as `[String: String?]`

My question is where is the difference in terms of setting `nil` value between dictionary declared as `[String: String]` and `[String: String?]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dict["key"] = nil` is a shorthand to removing the key from the dictionary (same as using `dict.removeValue(forKey: "key")`). If there was a value under the `"key"` key, after this line the *whole* entry is removed from the dictionary (both the key and the value).

Read the subscripts [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2885650-subscript) to learn more:

> If you assign nil as the value for the given key, the dictionary removes that key and its associated value.
>
> In the following example, the key-value pair for the key "Aquamarine" is removed from the dictionary by assigning nil to the key-based subscript.
>
> ```
> hues["Aquamarine"] = nil
> print(hues)
> // Prints "["Coral": 18, "Heliotrope": 296, "Cerise": 330]"
> ```

`let value = dict["key"]` gets the value for the key, and by definition returns `nil` if there is no entry for the given key (which is in your case).

According to [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2885650-subscript), subscript returns either the value, or nil, if the key is not in the dictionary:

> The value associated with key if key is in the dictionary; otherwise, nil.

Answer (score 1):

`dict["key"] = nil` means you are removing the item from dictionary. The return type of `dict[someKey]` is Optional as the key may not be there.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider implementing:

```
dict["key"] = nil
```

as the same as calling [`removeValue(forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/1641348-removevalue):

```
dict.removeValue(forKey: "key")
```

By default, getting a value from a dictionary would returns an *optional* value:

```
var dict = [String: String]()
dict["key"] = "Hello"

let value = dict["key"] // Optional("Hello")
```

Note that the type of `value` is optional string (String?).

Comment: @dwonvoter it is inappropriate to downvote without mentioning what's the reason if it :)